# ignore whitespace and lines begining with # in php

Tags: php

As per title, I am importing a file, each line is then exploded to separate out the different parts of the line, however I have some lines which begin with either '#' or whitespace, all of which should be ignored. How is best to do this?

Comment: do you want to include a certain file or just to read its content?

Comment: Do you want to remove all of the white spaces and '#' , or only those in the beginning?

Comment: This is the most basic of text handling, and no indication that you've tried anything yourself. Have you consulted PHP's documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can test each line using a regex to find and remove # or whitespace (\s).

```
$data = file('theFile.txt');
$lines = array();
foreach ($data as $line) {
  $lines[] = preg_replace('/^(#|\s)+/','', $line)
}

var_dump($lines);
```

Comment: Still doesnot remove the slashes. And its not about skipping line containing # or white space, the problem is to remove white space and # .

Comment: OK, so "all of which should be ignored" means it should remove those chars?! where are the slashes? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Adjusted the answer to remove unwanted chars.

Comment: I think this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to remove leading white spaces and #:

```
$data = file('theFile.txt');
$lines = array();
foreach ($data as $line) {
  $lines[] = preg_replace('/^(#|\s)+/', '', $line);
}

var_dump($lines);
```